# Jdbc separate databases for reading and writing operations

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, web-applications

I know there are similar questions but I want to ask for advice for my particular case. I have a web application that use jdbc. This application, at startup, is creating a Map of connections. When a db change need to be done a connection from this map(there are multiple connection for more db's and reading and writing are done on the same db for every one of them) is send in DAO class using the constructor of that class and using that connection the query is executed. 
The thing is that now a change need to be done: reading and writing will be done on two different db's and the code need to be changed in order for this to work. I need to know what is the best approach to make the change.

Comment: Add your current code so that we can help.

Comment: Why do you send a database connection to the DAO class per constructor? Isn't such a connection typically permanently reused? And isn't the mangement of such a reusement typically done by a Database Server or the Application Server? Why do you wan't to have a fixed connection for a DAO? What would you do if a connection is blocking - do you want the connected DAO to be unuseable? What if many users want to use that DAO in parallel - do you really want to stop parallel working of such a DAO?

Comment: @NiklasP I have a pool of connections and i can chose from there what connection to chose. Because I send the connection to the DAO I don't have a fixed connection for that DAO. This arhitecture is already implemented I understood is not the best. I want to improve it and also make the change specified.